# How to recover a document from un properly closed tags in python?

Tags: python, html

Here is my problem

I have a sample text like

```
text="""<!--translated from:

The Dutch Royal Library

"""
```

now I tried to strip this text from tags, but I always get this error using this code

```
t = html.fromstring(text)
ctext = t.text_content()
```

and my error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    t = html.fromstring(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 634, in fromstring
    doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 535, in document_fromstring
    "Document is empty")
lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty
```

I traced the bug I found that removing unclosed

I already tried using BeautifulSoup

and here is my code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
print soup.prettify()
```

but no use, so can anyone help me?

Comment: The `<!--` is an un-closed comment tag.

Comment: I know, but I am dealing with about 2 Gb data and I faced this bug in parsing, so I need my script to handle this

Comment: I think you should use a regexp to change the tag or extract the data.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey: I've heard it's futile to parse html with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the unclosed tag:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text[4:])
print soup.prettify()
```

Then BeautifulSoup will be able to find the content. You can have more information about this library at their [documentation page](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: actually I have comment tag, <!-- but its un closed which is making the problems

Comment: So try removing the undesired block of text